# What machine learning methods can be used to minimise the difference to a target 2D boolean matrix with differing sizes?

Tags: neural-networks

I have a problem whereby given an input, the difference that is generated from the model to a target **2D boolean matrix** needs to be minimised.

The target boolean matrix can be of varying shape, i.e: 10 x 10, 100 x 100, 500 x 500 etc depending on the input. Naively, I was thinking of having 100 output nodes for the case of 10 x 10 matrix but the number of outputs becomes too huge when it is 100 x 100 matrix and so forth.

Alternatively, I was thinking about a regression model that outputs the number of `1` labels. However, this approach doesn't consider the position of the values in the 2D matrix.

Is there a way to efficiently learn a model for this problem?

Comment: please provide an actual example

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I would like to provide an actual example but it would be divulging an unpublished work that I'm working on for my research. However, please let me know if anything is not clear with my posting. I'm happy to clarify.

Comment: well, you give little to no information about the problem... the best I can say is to lookup gans generator or diffusion models, they usually have to deal with high dimensional outputs... but they use a ton of inductive bias to make it happen, whcih might not hold in your case

Comment: Maybe you can factorize/decompose your target matrix with a fixed dimensionality, and then let the network learn such fixed factorization, and finally recompose the full matrix by using the components learned by the network.